# how to assign value to string and calculate in for loop

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to assign value to each character on a string input, calculate the total and then displaying the output on a label. here's how i tried to implement it, by using switch, however the result still shows '0'. how do I solve this error?
thanks. the code is run on on-Click event in C#

```
string passport = "ABC123";
            char[] array;
            array = passport.ToCharArray(0,6);
            int total = 0;
            foreach (char c in array) { 
            switch (passport)
            {
                case "A":
                    total += 1;
                    break;

                case "B":
                    total += 2;
                    break;

                case "C":
                    total += 3;
                    break;

                case "1":
                    total += 1;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    total += 2;
                    break;

                case "3":
                    total += 3;
                    break;

            }
            }
            Label1.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: You're doing your switch on `passport` rather than `c`.

Comment: ops my bad. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Make hardcoded values a type of `char`(with single quote) otherwise it will not compile. `case 'A':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the Comments as answer.

```
string passport = "ABC123";
char[] array = passport.ToCharArray(0,6);
int total = 0;
foreach (char c in array) { 
    switch (c) // You're doing your switch on passport rather than c. – Loocid 
    {
        case 'A': //Make hardcoded values a type of char(with single quote) otherwise it will not compile. case 'A': – Fabio
            total += 1;
            break;

        case 'B':
            total += 2;
            break;

        case 'C':
            total += 3;
            break;

        case '1':
            total += 1;
            break;

        case '2':
            total += 2;
            break;

        case '3':
            total += 3;
            break;

    }
}
Label1.Text = total.ToString();
```